# How to pass to sort function req.query.sort?

Tags: node.js, json, mongoose

I have a router that is supposed to retrieve sorted data,
using node and  mongoose

```
router.get('/api/users/',
async (req:Request, res:Response)=> {

const users = await User.find({}).sort();

res.send(users);

});


User.find({}).sort();
```

req.query.sort = ["name","DESC"] as a **string** not an array and not an object!

as I know sort expects to Json object but JSON.parse() not work. assume because the square brackets.

I wonder what is the right way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

use `body-parser` module so just try in index file

```
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```

and in router file :

```
let item : string[]= JSON.parse(req.query.sort);
let object = {}
object[item[0]] = item[1];
const users = await User.find({}).sort(object)
```

Comment: thank's, 
 let item = JSON.parse(req.query.sort);  gives an error :Argument of type 'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: when you run the `JSON.parse(req.query.sort)` do have any error? what's the error message?

Comment: Yes. 
 error TS2345: Argument of type 
'string | ParsedQs | string[] | ParsedQs[] | undefined' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'string'.      

14   let item = JSON.parse(req.query.sort);

Comment: I'm using typescript maybe because typescript not sure req.query.sort is defined

Comment: I tested in typescript online, there isn't any error, can you show me the result of console.log(req.query.sort)

Comment: ["email","DESC"]

Comment: the req.query.sort is not string so you don't need to parse

Comment: I mentioned in the question: req.query.sort = ["name","DESC"] as a string not an array and not an object!
console.log(typeof req.query.sort) gives string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// I found an example may help you

router.get("/users", async (req, res) => {
const match = {};
const sort = {};

// if (req.query.FirstName){
// match.Firstname=req.query.Firstname==="John" }

if (req.query.sortBy) {
const parts = req.query.sortBy.split(":");
sort[parts[0]] = parts[1] === "desc" ? -1 : 1;
}

 try {
 await req.user
  .populate({
    path: "users",
    match,
    options: {
      limit: parseInt(req.query.limit),
      skip: parseInt(req.query.skip),
      sort,
    },
   })
    .execPopulate();
  //  res.render("users/user_list", {
  //  userlist: req.user.users,

  res.send(req.user.users)
  
   });
  
   } catch (e) {
   res.status(500).send();
   }
  });

 //https:....  /users?sortBy=createdAt%3Aasc&limit=10&skip=0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73137125/edit) to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)